# React.js download image from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, download, imagedownload

I have React.js and Node.js application. In that application I need to download image from URL like normal download which stores image in browser's downloads.

I have tried many methods from frontend (React) as well as backend (node.js by calling api to save image).
Unfortunately most of solution opening image in new tab, some downloading file in unsupported format.

I tried like following code samples from React

1.

```
<a href="https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png" download="https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png"> Download Here </a>
```

2. Using Link

Link to="https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png" target="_blank" download>Download</Link

3.

```
const downloadFile = (
  filePath,
  fileName = 'myimg.png',
) => {
  fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + filePath, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',
    },
  })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = url;
      link.download = fileName;

      document.body.appendChild(link);

      link.click();

      link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    });
};

<button
        onClick={() => downloadFile('https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png')}
      >
        Download my image
      </button>
```

4. Tried with `js-file-download`  package

Above methods and some other solutions are not working as expected.

Please help to download image from url in browser's download
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As of late 2018, clicking the link won’t trigger a download if the resource to be downloaded wasn’t served from the same origin or same server. Apparently, this is restriction is a security measure.

[It would be help to you.](https://medium.com/charisol-community/downloading-resources-in-html5-a-download-may-not-work-as-expected-bf63546e2baa)

Answer (score 0):

To download an image to a local system using an anchor () tag and a URL in a React component, you can create a link with the href attribute pointing to the image URL, and set the download attribute to specify the desired filename.

```
const imageUrl = 'https://help.twitter.com/content/dam/help-twitter/brand/logo.png';
const filename = 'image.jpg'; // Specify the desired file name

<a href={imageUrl} download={filename}>
  Click here to download the image
</a>
```

Comment: This will only open image in tab not download in browse's downloads. is your solution different from one which I tried (mentioned in question point 1) ? does browser/ browser version matters ?

Comment: @kungfuKenny, it was not correct answer.